# Metax alternative for Linux

Tags: software-recommendation, mp4, tag

I have used the Metax program on my Windows that works great for video, and was wondering if there was a Linux video, mp4, movie and TV show editor out there. I tried using EasyTAG to do it, but it lacks the feature of letting me embed a poster image on the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Kid3** which is available in Ubuntu Software Center. It has the ability to add album artwork image.